# build dev failed: Cannot set property 'fileSystem' of null

Tags: linux, ionic2

I am on Linux Debian 
I had this error a few times
I tried to install uninstall with npm install and npm uninstall

```
ionic -v
2.1.14

> ionic-app-scripts serve

[11:15:49]  ionic-app-scripts 0.0.47 
[11:15:49]  watch started ... 
[11:15:49]  build dev started ... 
[11:15:49]  clean started ... 
[11:15:49]  clean finished in 3 ms 
[11:15:49]  copy started ... 
[11:15:49]  transpile started ... 
[11:15:51]  transpile finished in 2.19 s 
[11:15:51]  webpack started ... 
[11:15:51]  build dev failed: Cannot set property 'fileSystem' of null 
[11:15:51]  dev server running: http://localhost:8100/
```

My problem is different I installed `ionic-app-scripts 0.0.47` like I read in the others answers but it doesn't work I have also tried 
`@ionic/app-scripts@latest` but it doesn't work I have this error 
`build dev failed: Cannot set property 'fileSystem' of null`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [build dev failed: Cannot set property 'fileSystem' of null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719924/build-dev-failed-cannot-set-property-filesystem-of-null)

Comment: If you have installed latest ionic cli.. get ionic-app-scripts 1.0.0..check the answer

Comment: "*I installed `ionic-app-scripts 0.0.47` like I read in the others answers*" - that is not what the answers said. Where did you read that?

Comment: npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest give me this error `@ionic/app-scripts@1.0.0  invalid`

Comment: change the version of app scripts in your package.json then delete node-modules and then do npm install

Comment: check the other answer for package.json

Answer (score 1):

Install this :  `"@ionic/app-scripts": "1.0.0"` version of app-scripts in your package.json.

This error came after npm update or ionic lib update (I wanted to test these commands... BIG MISTAKE).

Be careful with lib update.