# Ionic 2 project not running

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ionic2

I have created an Ionic 2 side menu project and did all the required installations for Ionic 2 in VS 2015. But it still has this message when running the project:

> You're almost ready! If you're seeing this page, then you still need to install the NPM Task Runner extension for Visual Studio and run this app again. You can download the extension from: https://aka.ms/ctmhio

I installed the NPM Task Runner from the website, but the message still appears. I tried restarting VS after the installation with no luck.

Comment: Have you try to use the command line for run your project? `$ ionic serve` in the path of your project?

Comment: I faced the same issue i have addressed the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719924/build-dev-failed-cannot-set-property-filesystem-of-null/45864150#45864150)

Answer (score 1):

This issue probably results from using the outdated node/npm version shipped with VS2015.

To fix this, download newest version of node.js and in VS go to *Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/External Web Tools* and move the $(PATH) entry to the top. Now VS will use your external installed npm version.

Then restore your dependencies by right click on dependencies in solution explorer and select restore packages. Now your app should build and run successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I got this message and I followed this part of instructions from [Get started with Ionic 2 apps in Visual Studio](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-ionic2/) and the message disappeared.

1. Open the Task Runner Explorer: In Visual Studio, open the View menu, select Other Windows then Task Runner Explorer. You can also use the keyboard shortcut: Ctrl + Alt + Backspace.
2. Right click the ionic:build task and choose the Bindings -> Project Open menu to setup the watch task to run when you load your project.
3. Run your Ionic app in the Ripple browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try with ionic 1. I think there are some problems with v2 for a few days.

Answer (score 0):

```
1) Download Visual Studio Code
2) Install node.js
3) npm install -g cordova ionic
4) ionic start YOUR_PROJECT_NAME sidemenu
5) cd YOUR_PROJECT_NAME
6) ionic serve
```

I am sure this will work for you.

For mode you can go http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/